# Какой БД выбрать для ERP-систему, SQL или NoSQL?

Tags: sql, база-данных, проектирование, nosql

Есть ERP система которые назначен для складский учет(плюс в будущим подключаем к маркетплейс и выпускаем API для внешнего пользования).  Сейчас запустили как MVP и проект запустился успешно. Все добавки и правки сделали. Коротко говоря для БД точная схема определено. Теперь пока система работает и тестируется, хотим переписать с нуля под новым стеком. Выбираем БД которые подходят именно для таких проектов. Подскажите пожалуйста, стоит ли переходит на NoSQL(сейчас проект работает на Postgresql) или все же SQL хороший выбор? Сейчас в БД не так много данные но в будущим проекта ждет хорошая нагрузка, сто или тыс записи/чтение в секундах. Проект строен под микросервисную архитектуру. Поэтому можем использовать и то и другое. NoSQL а рекомендуют многие, говорят бистре чем SQL но я думаю с SQL ом проблема не будет если сделать архитектуру правильно(индексы, связи, кеширование и т.д).
Пока читаю всякие статье об этом, изучаю но лишнего совета не бывает) Если вы сталкивались с подобными проблемами, подскажите пожалуйста)

Comment: Постгря прекрасно справляется с большими нагрузками с учетом правильной архитектуры таблиц,  нормализации и при наличии мэмкеша типа редиса